# How can uniswapv2router return WETH address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, uniswap

In implementation about uniswapv2router, `uniswapv2router.WETH()` returns the canonical WETH address.

I want to know how it returns the WETH address. One thing I know is that in the uniwapv2router.sol code, the constructor sets the `WETH` value. However, in the below example, I can't see any value given in initialization of `uniswapRouter`. Sorry for the newbie question!

```
pragma solidity 0.7.1;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract UniswapExample {
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ;

  IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
  address private multiDaiKovan = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;

  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }

  function convertEthToDai(uint daiAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    uniswapRouter.swapETHForExactTokens{ value: msg.value }(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI(), address(this), deadline);
    
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  function getEstimatedETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return uniswapRouter.getAmountsIn(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI());
  }

  function getPathForETHtoDAI() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = multiDaiKovan;
    
    return path;
  }
  
  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
```

This snippet initializes a pointer to a contract deployed on the specified address (`UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS`), assuming it implements the `IUniswapV2Router02` interface.

If you wanted to deploy the specified contract, you'd need to use the `new` keyword:

```
// can't deploy an interface, needs to be a contract
UniswapV2Router02 newlyDeployedRouter = new UniswapV2Router02(
    // constructor params
    factoryAddress,
    wethAddress
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source code of UniswapV2Router02.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol)

In the `UniswapExample` contract example that you passed, in the constructor, the contract is getting reference to the already deployed `UniswapV2Router02` contract.

```
 constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }
```

Now `uniswapRouter` is a reference to the UniswapV2Router02 contract. If you check the source code, there is this:

```
  address public immutable override WETH;
```

which is set in its constructor:

```
constructor(address _factory, address _WETH) public {
    factory = _factory;
    WETH = _WETH;
 }
```

Since `WETH` is a public variable, solidity assigns it a getter function. Calling `uniswapv2router.WETH()` will return that `WETH` address